# Log4j2 is not reading configuration file

Tags: java, debugging, logging, log4j, log4j2

Please be nice, I'm brand new to logging and am encountering some issues with log4j2, even after trying many things and following the documentation to a tee.

I have spent my entire morning trying to figure out how to get log4j2 to print a simple debug message. I have consulted every resource, relevant piece of documentation, and answer on StackOverflow.

It seems that log4j2 is always using the default configuration no matter what I do. I have tried setting the configuration file location from the command line, still with no luck.

There are other dependencies in my classpath that use logging, such as Playwright. I am not sure if this affects my issue.

Running `mvn clean test -Dlog4j.debug` produces the following message. I am not sure exactly what this means, or if it is relevant, after searching for a while:

```
WARN StatusLogger Multiple logging implementations found:
Factory: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory, Weighting: 10
Factory: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory, Weighting: 15
Using factory: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContextFactory
```

Java:

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

class ExampleClass {
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    void main() {
        logger.debug("Hello world")
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/log4j2.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.toughdata.autogrowth</groupId>
  <artifactId>autogrowth</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>autogrowth</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!--maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target-->
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>

        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.toughdata.autogrowth.CLI</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                      <mainClass>com.toughdata.autogrowth.CLI</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>    
                <mainClass>com.toughdata.autogrowth.server.Server</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>9</source>
                  <target>9</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
    
      <resources>
          <resource>
              <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          </resource>
      </resources>

  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Argparse -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.argparse4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>argparse4j</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Playwright -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.playwright</groupId>
      <artifactId>playwright</artifactId>
      <version>1.39.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring boot web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring boot test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JavaMail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20230618</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: despite what you say, its seems there is multiple logging framework implementation in your classpath. I dont know why you tell us about `mvn clean test` and show us a `main` funcion. pls show `pom.xml`

Comment: I think you are right that there are multiple logging implementations. I am using Playwright Java if that means anything. How do I deal with this? Will post pom.xml in a sec

Comment: there are several issues, first of all  why you use spring-boot without inheriting the project from parent ? 2nd, spring boot use lombok by default, to use properly log4j you have to exclude lombok ! there are other stuff that are redundant. Try to simplyfy your project following spring-boot documentation !

Comment: Wow, that's interesting about lombok... I did not know this. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi Thank you, that solved my issues. It turns out that simplifying my pom.xml did the trick. This isn't a spring project anyways, i don't know why spring boot was in there. Oops. Please make an answer so I can mark this as solved.

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi Can you expand on the Lombok/Log4J issue? I haven't experienced a problem.

Comment: sorry, typo, I ment logback, not lombok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several issues

- first of all why you use spring-boot without inheriting the project from parent ?
- 2nd, spring boot use logback by default, to use properly log4j you have to exclude logback ! there are other stuff that are redundant. Try to simplify your project following spring-boot documentation !

this is a sample version of your pom, simplified

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- EDIT #1 : set project parent to inherit structure and dependencies-->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.toughdata.autogrowth</groupId>
    <artifactId>autogrowth</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>autogrowth</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <!-- EDIT #2: do not need compiler.release/target/source, just java.version, spring boot do the magic -->
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <!--EDIT #3: complete remove pluginManagement, spring-boot do the magic for you -->
        <plugins>
            <!--EDIT #4 removing version and configuration from maven-plugin, is inherited-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--EDIT #5 removing compiler, all you need is inherited -->
        </plugins>

        <!--EDIT #6 removing src/main/resources, is maven default-->
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Argparse -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.argparse4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>argparse4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Playwright -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.playwright</groupId>
            <artifactId>playwright</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--EDIT #7 removing version from all dependencies inherited-->
        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- EDIT #8 - exluding default logging system to avoid conflicts -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaMail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <!-- QUESTION ?!? do you really need this, i don't think so !-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230618</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--EDIT #9 - removing log4j explicit version, adding via spring-boot dependency-->
        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. I had Spring boot dependency in a project that wasn't even using spring. Doh!